# What is the csilogfile for?

Tags: .net, windows, logging

I am developing dot net applications. Yesterday a friend of mine told me about the log-folder "C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage". If the folder exists and i run my program then a file called "csilogfile.log" will be created.

My question is:
What is this log file for? Can i disabled this loggin mechanism?

Comment: What does it contain?

Comment: logging stuff about my application (and i think about some other applications too)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a log file for the [Component Servicing Infrastructure](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx) (CSI). Its location can be configured using the `windows_tracing_logfile` environment variable (since Vista). If you set the `windows_tracing_flags` to a high value, even more will be logged. I don't think it's specific to the .NET Framework.

BVT's are [Build Verification Tests](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/24201-Windows-7-SP1-RTM-7601-17514-101119-1850-leaked/page136#post_370376), a set of tests Microsoft runs on every new build of its operating systems.

Comment: FYI CSI link - see archive.org - http://web.archive.org/web/20160121220429/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx